# Guiding "dot" towards desired edge placement

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have the following Graphviz code.

```
digraph {
   North -> West
   North -> East
   North -> South
   West-> South
   East -> South
}
```

When using dot on this input file, it renders the graph with the direct edge between the North and South nodes on the outside:

[image: Rendered by dot]

My question: **how can I get dot to render the North-to-South edge in between the East and West nodes?**

Note that the graph above is a much simplified version of the problem I am encountering in the graph I actually want to improve, shown below (the thick red edge is the one I'd like dot to route via the more obvious way).

[image: The issue in real life]

Answer (score 1):

Pretty gross, but this works.
Uses a 3x3 matrix of nodes (visible & invisible).
Aligns via **rank=same** (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/rank/) & the **group** (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/group/) attribute.  There is probably a "better" way to do this, but ...

```
digraph {
  splines=false

  North -> West 
  North -> East 
  North -> South
  West-> South
  East -> South

  node[shape=plain style=invis label=""]
  edge[style=invis]
  {rank=same West -> central -> East }
  {rank=same l1   -> North   -> r1 } 
  {rank=same l2   -> South   -> r2 } 
  { node [group=V]  North-> central-> South}
  { node [group=L]  l1 -> West-> l2}
  { node [group=R]  r1 -> East -> r2}  
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: I appreciate this, but the real graph I'm trying to get to behave is way more complicated, and I'd like to avoid an approach like this because the hard-coding of the desired geometry doesn't scale well.

Comment: Can you say more about the real graph/problem?

Comment: Well it's much bigger, and I see 'dot' take these weird detours, preferring to go around  the nodes in a layer rather than picking a perfectly obvious path between nodes.

Comment: I've added a picture of the real-life problematic graph in the question.

Comment: It seems that dot really wants to avoid edges to go between nodes in lower layers. Your solution hacks around this by introducing a fake node. I could do that for my real graph as well, but I am now mostly wondering if there is some setting that influences this behavior.

Comment: There is a Graphviz Issue (https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/1417) with the same problem.  Can't suggest any attributes to change, but a small possibility that this will help:  dot myfile |neato -TX -n >out.X  // uses neato to route edges (https://www.graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a specific edge to dominate your layout, you can use the `weight = <integer>` (where integer is a small positive value of about 10) attribute to make it as direct as possible. Conversely, negative values allow the layout engine to use more circuitous routes for unimportant edges. Edges with different weights are prioritised, but the layout is difficult to predict and can unexpectedly become ugly.

Avoid placing these additional constraints unnecessarily as the layout becomes increasingly brittle and small changes to the source can completely change the output.